# JavaScript/CSS3 Slider - bxslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made ​​on the basis of the script BxSlider slider on its website.
Structure slider is as such:

```
<ul class="slider-cont">
    <li>
        <img src="images/slide-1.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="caption">caption1.</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/slide-2.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="caption">caption2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/slide-3.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="caption">caption3</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Caption is over the image and is the way to the left of the slider. My question is whether it is possible using CSS3 or JS to do the same animation to make the text more quickly, "rolling off" and "rode" than the picture? I tried using the tool in the bxslider. `OnSlideBefore` or `OnSlideAfter` but I managed to get this effect.

Comment: I've never used BxSlider before can you post the code on a fiddle so we can better understand your question?  I'm unsure of what problem you're trying to solve specifically.  Thanks

Comment: Namely I want to get the parallax effect, where the text disappears faster than the left side of the image. Just want the text to appear sooner than the picture.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. I think you're asking if there's a way to animate the image caption separately to slide itself but without an example of the problem (try [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) its annoyingly difficult to answer.

Comment: I want to get the effect of the text and background it here:
http://www.sequencejs.com/themes/sliding-horizontal-parallax/

Text rolls off within 2000 ms.
Background (image) in 3000ms.

I want to use in bxslider. Is used to JS? Or CSS3?

Comment: I doubt the timing is done in CSS.  Css3 animations arent fully cross browser compliant yet, hence the js solution. Open your script files and search the docs.  If you know for a fact it is 2000 ms, search the doc for "2000" or try looking for "set timeout".